# hstack/index function with duplicate values

Tags: excel, indexing, excel-formula, lookup

Is there a way I can populate all the Agents to Table 2 that is currently on "On Call" status?

[image]

I am currently using HSTACK and INDEX function. If the agent's status is "On Call" from Table 1, all agents and their corresponding duration would populate Table 2 as shown in the picture.

Now my problem is there are instances that agents would have the same duration. If this happens, my formula would only return the first value from Table 1 for the Agents instead of all the Agents regardless if they have the same value for duration or not as long as their **STATUS** is "On Call".

See on the picture, it only return Agent 5 with the duration 0:02:40, instead of Agent 5, Agent 8, and Agent 11 on that column.

How would I be able to return all the value for the Agent with duplicate value for their duration?

Here is the exact formula I am currently using on cell E4 right now

```
=HSTACK(INDEX($A$4:$C$14,MATCH(SORT(FILTER($C$4:$C$14,($B$4:$B$14=E2),""),1,-1),$C$4:$C$14,0),1),TEXT(SORT(FILTER($C$4:$C$14,($B$4:$B$14=E2),""),1,-1),"[h]:mm:ss"))
```

Comment: Can't you do this a lot more simply with just FILTER and SORT and maybe INDEX?

Comment: `=SORT(FILTER(HSTACK($A$4:$A$14,$C$4:$C$14),$B$4:$B$14=E2),2,-1)`

Comment: I can also go with that it is fine as long as I can get all the values returned

Comment: @ScottCraner I'm on it. Wait a min

Comment: @ScottCraner works like a charm! This is exactly what I need. It populates everyone on the list with the same value on the duration. Thank you so much!

Comment: You could try this as well : `=CHOOSECOLS(SORT(FILTER(A4:C14,B4:B14=E2),3,-1),1,3)`

Comment: this also worked @MayukhBhattacharya with the same output thank you so much

Comment: I have posted both the solutions by @ScottCraner Sir, as well as mine to close the post.

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya Sorting fewer columns might be preferable: `=SORT(CHOOSECOLS(FILTER(A4:C14,B4:B14=E2),1,3),2,-1)`!?

Comment: Agree @VBasic2008 Sir, bt in `MS365` with spill arrays it hardly matters works good for two or three. btw I am adding your formula as well in the answer

Comment: everything looks great! thank you all in responding to my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use either of the one as per your wish:

[image]

---

As suggested by **[Scott Craner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4851590/scott-craner)** Sir,

• Formula used in cell `E4`

```
=SORT(FILTER(HSTACK($A$4:$A$14,$C$4:$C$14),$B$4:$B$14=E2),2,-1)
```

---

As suggested by **[VBasic2008](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9814069/vbasic2008)** Sir,

• Formula used in cell `K4`

```
=SORT(CHOOSECOLS(FILTER(A4:C14,B4:B14=K2),1,3),2,-1)
```

---

Or,

• Formula used in cell `H4`

```
=CHOOSECOLS(SORT(FILTER(A4:C14,B4:B14=H2),3,-1),1,3)
```

---